# Wrong sort order on category page Magento 2.3.0

Tags: category, magento2.3, category-attribute

I have created an attribute that is used for sorting on the category pages.  The sorting order is numeric.
Expectation is that sorting order is:
 1. 1
 2. 2
 3. 11

But the actual sort order is:
 1. 1
 2. 11
 3. 2

Apparantly, Magento sorts on the first digit. Not on the complete integer.
How to effectuate the correct sort order?

Comment: Is this 2.2 or 2.3?

Comment: I am sorry: 2.3.0. Is it a known 2.3 issue?

Comment: You can use natsort Function of php after take that values in array.

Answer (score -1):

**You can use natsort Function of php after take that values in array.**

Or

You can do this by custom Query as:

> First add an order by clause at the end:

```
ORDER BY category_id
```

> Treat it like an integer. There are a few ways to do this but I usually add a zero.

```
ORDER BY category_id + 0
```

Hope This will help You!!

Comment: Oscprofessionals can you implement that for me. At what cost?